# Need to display list of followers information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am a ruby on rails beginner.

I have two models with one-to-many relationships and i want to get `followers_id` from `relationships` model and display the `followers` information

```
model1 

Users  -> has_many                      
id firstname lastname....
 1    sample   

model2

Relationships -> belongs_to              
user_id follower_id following_id
 1         2         
 1         3
```

I have tried using 'pluck' method of rails in (rails console)

```
u  = Users.find(1)

r  = u.relationships.pluck(:follower_id)
//gives me a array of id
```

But I don't know how to use these arrays of ids to get `followers` info(firstname,lastname)

Could someone please guide me..

Is there any better way to get followers info.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Your Model relationship

```
@user  = Users.find(1)

@follower_ids  = @user.relationships.pluck(:follower_id)
```

You get all the follower ids in @followers_ids

```
@followers = User.where("id in (?)", @followers_id)
```

You get all information of followers inside `@followers` variables

Comment: Why someone would do this in SQL DB, if it's much better solution just to use join (1  DB query vs 2 queries proposed in this solution) ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what You basically need is to connect Users with Followers **through** Relationships this is done like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :followers, through: :relationships
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :follower
end
```

After that You can just do `user.followers`